# How to implement Iterator if we don't know the type of the Elements in the Container Type?

Tags: java, list, generics, iterator, containers

I Want to implement an Iterator, but I don't know the type of the Elements of this Container-Type. I just know that my container type is "Ring", and a ring is a Container-Type, with the proprety, that after the last element comes the first one.

I don't know which Iterator should I implement, ie:

```
class RingIterator implements Iterator<???> 

private int pos = 0;
private List<?????> list;

RingIterator(List<? extends T> list) {
    //code here
}
```

what should come in the "????" spaces? I thought at the beginning "Rind" but I think it is not the right answer.. because Ring should contain other type of elements.. We have just an information about "Ring": it is a container type! (List or something like that..)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to create a generic class:

```
public class RingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! 

And
    private List<????> list;

Should it be List<T> too? 

The constructor's list parameter type is 100% correct, and we should  just continue the class and the list-variable definitions..